# MySQL: "IF (EXISTS A) AND (NOT EXISTS B) THEN..." is not working

Tags: mysql

I would like to user condition like this:

```
IF (EXISTS A) AND (NOT EXISTS B) THEN...
```

A and B conditions are like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE flag=1
```

E.g.:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE flag=1) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE flag=2)
THEN
    INSERT INTO table (id, name, flag) VALUES (0, 'name', 2);
END IF;
```

In this case, the "(EXISTS A) and (NOT EXISTS B)" condition is true.
but the query don't enter into 'THEN'.
Could i know what's wrong?

Comment: This looks odd - it seems you can have an infinite number of rows where flag = 1 but only 1 where flag = 2.  Is this because question is simplified or should name come into it somewhere

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, because question simplified ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IF` you are using is not available outside of a stored procedure or maybe trigger.  Instead, you should use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO yourTable (id, name, flag)
SELECT 0, 'name', 2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE flag = 1) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE flag = 2);
```